# Ember Data returns an array of internal models instead of actual data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm creating a new adapter and model and trying to fetch data to use it in my template. When I make a request in route, the data in the model looks like this:
[image: data from ember]

The actual response looks like this:

[image: actual data]

I really have no idea why ember store returns the data with wrong ID's(the first two objects are objects from the response - but the id fields don't match) and some internal methods.

Code for the adapter:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(UrlTemplates, {
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
  findAll() {
    const token = this.get('session.data.authenticated.access_token');
    return this.ajax(`${window.App.host}/distributor/${1}/companies?access_token=${token}`);
  }
});
```

Code for the router:

```
model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      companies: this.store.findAll('distributor/distributors')
    });
  },
```

Code for the model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  Name: DS.attr('string'),
  demo: DS.attr('number'),
  devices: DS.hasMany('distributor/devices', { async: true })
});
```

As you can see, this is pretty usual process.If I log data from the request in route, it is already mixed up. Considering Ember Data's data flow I assume that the data is being mixed up in the store. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Internal model is what EmberData always returns. It wraps your data in a few layers so that it can keep track of things. What I'm not sure about from your question is what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a workaround. I have created a simple serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  extractArray(firstArg, secondArg, payload) { 
    return this._super(firstArg, secondArg, payload);
  }
});
```

Not ideal, but it does the trick